# La fonction de « turn taking » et le « end of turn signal » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, terminologie, linguistique

[Ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32916) on discute de la fonction de [*turn-taking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn-taking) de *marqueurs discursifs/[de discours](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marqueur_de_discours)*, et en particulier de celle de *end of turn signal*. En commentaires ([1](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32910/francophones-seem-to-end-sentences-of-emotion-with-quoi#comment67602_32916),[2](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32910/francophones-seem-to-end-sentences-of-emotion-with-quoi#comment67603_32916)) on explique de manière vraiment intéressante que la notion de *[tour](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tour/2) de [parole](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parole)* ([?](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tour_de_parole)) pourrait être utile. Peut-on vérifier ?

---

- Comment traduit-on les termes *turn-taking* et le *end of turn
  signal* en linguistique ?
- Peut-on brièvement les définir et/ou illustrer à l'aide d'un exemple de phrase comment les deux seraient utilisés (et reliés) avec le nom *marqueurs
  discursif/de discours* ?

Comment: Il peut être utile de valider si les solutions fonctionnent avec les phrases : « One of the main function of discourse markers is turn-taking [...] » ; « "Quoi" as a discourse marker is an end of turn signal ».

Answer (score 1):

Le meilleur moyen de traduire turn-taking est : **tour de rôle** ou encore **prise de parole à tour de rôle.**

En réalité, je ne vois pas de mot français qui traduit littéralement le turn-taking si ce n'est qu'on emploie le mot anglais.

La plupart des articles ne savent pas non plus comment traduire ce terme, donc ils le traduisent avec une phrase expliquant la fonction elle-même du terme. Mais en termes de probabilité, il est vrai que "tour de rôle" apparaît plus souvent.

[image]

Pour le *end of turn signal*, même remarque, la meilleure traduction selon moi reste celle mot à mot, ce qui donnerait : **signal de fin de tour** ou **signal de fin de prise de parole**, ou encore **signal de fin de tour de rôle**.

C'est très lourd, raison pour laquelle on préférera prononcer à l'américaine.

Answer (score 1):

Dans un contexte de discours, d'interaction langagière, je dirais :

- turn-taking : prise de parole
- end-of-turn signal : signal d'alternance